# Error: Can't combine <character> and <double> using bind_rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to read multiple csv. files and join them into one.

So I originally have:

```
d <- list.files(path="data/", full.names = TRUE, pattern = "\\.csv$") %>%
  lapply(read_csv) %>%
 bind_rows
```

I get the following error:

Error: Can't combine `rt` character and `rt` double.

I imagine this must be because rt is a variable which sometimes is a number and otherwise is null.

I tried to change rt into double with mutate, like this:

```
d <- list.files(path="data/", full.names = TRUE, pattern = "\\.csv$") %>%
  lapply(read_csv) %>%as.data.table()%>%mutate(across(rt, as.double))%>%
 bind_rows
```

However when I do that I run into a more complicated problem. I get the following message:

Item 1 has 541 rows but longest item has 583; recycled with remainder.Item 3 has 561 rows but longest item has 583; recycled with remainder.Item 4 has 473 rows but longest item has 583; recycled with remainder.Item 5 has 575 rows but longest item has 583; recycled with remainder.Item 6 has 4 rows but longest item has 583; recycled with remainder.Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i NAs introduced by coercion
i Input `..1` is `across(rt, as.double)`.NAs introduced by coercion

it seems (from my understanding) that one of the csv files is longer than the other and for this reason only one of them is mutated and only one of them is binded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve diagnosed the problem correctly. Your fix fails to work because you forgot that you are working on a *list* of `data.frame`s. You are converting them to one single `data.table` via `as.data.table`, but this won’t do what you want it to do. Instead, you need to use lapply (or similar) to perform the fix (i.e. the column conversion) on all of your tables in the list:

```
d <- list.files(path = "data", full.names = TRUE, pattern = "\\.csv$") %>%
  lapply(read_csv) %>%
  lapply(\(x) mutate(x, across(rt, as.double))) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but what happens to the `as.data.table` function? doesn't the mutate verb need it to be in something that is not a list?

Comment: @josefc95 I honestly don’t understand why you’re using `as.data.table` here anyway. Nothing in the code requires using ‘data.table’ at all. Are you confusing `data.frame` and `data.table`? Unless your other code uses it, don’t even load that package. As for your other question, yes, `mutate` of course requires a table — and it *gets* a table! The result of your first `lapply` is a list of tables (namely, one table per `read_csv` call). And the second `lapply` calls `mutate` on each of these tables in turn.

Comment: This makes so much sense! I thought they were the same thing! Thank you so much for your help!!!