# Add file creation date as a colum when creating data from from files using map_df R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to add the file creation date as a column to a data frame I'm building using map_df (This code was given to me so I'm pretty lost).

I have a folder with several csv files which are organised roughly like this

| participant | rt | response | stimulus | condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 112 | 'e' | star.jpg | congruent |
| 1 | 150 | 'i' | diamond.jpg | congruent |

for an experiment which I pulling together like so..

```r
df <-   list.files(path = "C:/file_location", pattern = "*.csv") %>% map_df(~read_csv(.))
```

I realised that if I wanted to add the file creation date I would have to add it at this point, so I've tried

```r
df <- list.files(path = "C:/data location/", pattern = "*.csv") %>%      
    imap_dfc(~read_csv(.)%>%             
    mutate(Date_Created = file.info(.x)$ctime))
```

but it keeps returning an error

```
Error in 'dplyr::bind_cols()\': ! Can't recycle '..1' (size 1400) to match
'..2'(size 1425). Backtrace:
1. ... %\>% map_df(bind_cols)
2. purrr::imap_dfc(., \~read_csv(.) %\>% mutate(Date_Created =
   file.info(.x)$ctime))
3. dplyr::bind_cols(res)\
```

I've tried adding bind_cols to imap_dfc, but that still returns the same error. while searching for answers I saw that there [is some kind of issue in dplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5300) but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use this info.

(Sorry about the poor formatting there is an issue somewhere I can't find and it really only wants to let me publish a certain way)

**Edit:**
A few things have been tried to figure this out, but the below works but prints a warning

```
dfiles<-  list.files(path = "C:/file location", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
df<- purrr::map_df(L2ufiles, ~read_csv(.x)%>%
            mutate(EndDate = file.info(.x)$ctime,
                   rt=as.double(rt))) #needed to be added but seems to do nothing?
```

Which returns

```
Warning: There was 1 warning in mutate().
ℹ In argument: rt = as.double(rt).
Caused by warning:
! NAs introduced by coercion
```

But the data frame gets built, so close enough

Comment: do you still get the same error if you use `full.names = TRUE` with list.files?

Comment: Yeah same error :(

Comment: how odd! I was going to post an answer similar to r2evans's one, but then they posted theirs. Have you tried their answer?

Comment: I have and it almost gets me there, but only on two rows of two files

Comment: hmm interesting! Can you add something about the errors you are getting to your question? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `map_df` is the right starting point:

- `imap_*` is going to provide two arguments to the inner function: the values (filenames) themselves as `.y`, and either their names (if defined) or a sequence of integers as `.x`; you don't need the ints and don't have/need names, so this is not appropriate;
- `*map_dfc` combine by adding columns instead of by adding rows, I think you need the latter.

I have a few files laying around, I'll read two lines (`n_max=2`) from each for demonstration (don't use `n_max` yourself):

```r
library(dplyr)

files <- list.files("~/Downloads/", pattern="mt.*csv$", full.names=TRUE)

purrr::map_df(files, ~ read_csv(.x, n_max=2) %>%
    mutate(filesize = file.info(.x)$ctime))
# Rows: 2 Columns: 11
# ── Column specification ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
# Delimiter: ","
# dbl (11): mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb
# ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
# ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
# Rows: 2 Columns: 11
# ── Column specification ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
# Delimiter: ","
# dbl (11): mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb
# ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
# ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
# Rows: 2 Columns: 11
# ── Column specification ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
# Delimiter: ","
# dbl (11): mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb
# ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
# ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
# # A tibble: 6 × 12
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb filesize           
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
# 1   321     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 2023-07-27 09:55:35
# 2   321     6   160   110   3.9  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 2023-07-27 09:55:35
# 3   321     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 2023-07-27 10:02:41
# 4   321     6   160   110   3.9  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 2023-07-27 10:02:41
# 5    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 2023-07-27 09:48:33
# 6    21     6   160   110   3.9  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 2023-07-27 09:48:33
```

Also, `map_df` is superseded in lieu of `map` and either `purrr::list_rbind` or `dplyr::bind_rows` (both below are equivalent):

```r
purrr::map(files, ~ read_csv(.x, n_max=2) %>%
    mutate(filesize = file.info(.x)$ctime)) %>%
  purrr::list_rbind()

purrr::map(files, ~ read_csv(.x, n_max=2) %>%
    mutate(filesize = file.info(.x)$ctime)) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: So this sort of works, but it only returns the first two lines of the first two files. I tried changing `n_max=50` since that's the number of files I have but that returns an error 
`dplyr::bind_rows():
! Can't combine ..1$rt <character> and ..49$rt <double>.
Backtrace:`
So I found this question [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819014/error-cant-combine-character-and-double-using-bind-rows ]  but adding the `lapply` line returns this error `Error in UseMethod("mutate") :
no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`

Comment: Not sure if it matters but each file has over 1400 rows

Comment: `n_max ` limits the number of rows read by `read_csv`; it's used here to demonstrate that resulting date-time values actually do change with every input file, in your own code just leave it out.

Comment: @margusl ah! I had a feeling that was what was happening. 
So I just need to sort out the mutate issue. I did a weird thing that seems to work though returns an error. 
`df<- purrr::map_df(dfile, ~read_csv(.x)%>% mutate(date= file.info(.x)$ctime, rt=as.double(rt)))`
Which returns `Warning: There was 1 warning in mutate().
ℹ In argument: rt = as.double(rt)` but it creates the data frame soo.... call it a win?

Comment: Since you aren't defining `rt` in _that_ code expression, that means either it must exist in each of the files, or you have a vector in the global environment. In either case, I don't think `rt=` needs to be in this call to `mutate`. Sorry 'bout the `n_max=` thing, edited to reflect that more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach without `{purrr}`, utilizing `readr::read_csv()` support for a list of files (all files are combined, file name is stored in a separate column), `fs::dir_info()` and `dplyr::left_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

# some csv file examples generated from mtcars
files <- 
  fs::dir_info(glob = "mtcars*.csv") |> 
  select(path, modification_time)
files
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   path        modification_time  
#>   <fs::path>  <dttm>             
#> 1 mtcars0.csv 2023-06-25 15:48:52
#> 2 mtcars1.csv 2023-08-28 22:21:20
#> 3 mtcars2.csv 2023-08-28 22:22:14

read_csv(files$path, col_select = c(mpg, cyl, disp), id = "path") |>
  left_join(files)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(path)`
#> # A tibble: 96 × 5
#>    path          mpg   cyl  disp modification_time  
#>    <fs::path>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
#>  1 mtcars0.csv  21       6  160  2023-06-25 15:48:52
#>  2 mtcars0.csv  21       6  160  2023-06-25 15:48:52
#>  3 mtcars0.csv  22.8     4  108  2023-06-25 15:48:52
#>  4 mtcars0.csv  21.4     6  258  2023-06-25 15:48:52
#>  5 mtcars0.csv  18.7     8  360  2023-06-25 15:48:52
#>  6 mtcars0.csv  18.1     6  225  2023-06-25 15:48:52
#>  7 mtcars0.csv  14.3     8  360  2023-06-25 15:48:52
#>  8 mtcars0.csv  24.4     4  147. 2023-06-25 15:48:52
#>  9 mtcars0.csv  22.8     4  141. 2023-06-25 15:48:52
#> 10 mtcars0.csv  19.2     6  168. 2023-06-25 15:48:52
#> # ℹ 86 more rows
```

`fs::dir_info()` can be replaced with `list.files(pattern = "*csv$") |> file.info()` and extra columns (e.g. `path`) can be dropped.

<sup>Created on 2023-08-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I'm confused about what to replace here.  I've got
  `files <- list.files(pattern = "*csv$", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  file.info(.)$ctime`
which returns the error `Error in `$`(., file.info(.), ctime) : 
  3 arguments passed to '$' which requires 2`

Comment: `file.info()` returns a data.frame, if you want a `ctime` column as a vector, you could go for `list.files(pattern = "*csv$", full.names = TRUE) %>% file.info() %>% getElement("ctime")` .  Or `... %>% subset(select = ctime)`, if you want it as single-column data.frame where file names are row names.

Comment: Must say I didn't actually test `file.info() `  and in this exact setting and it does need some special handling before join can be used, though I didn't really expect that someone would not want to use  `{fs}`  with Tidyverse  :)